# Example make file for a drupal profile

Tags: aegir

I am trying to create a platform of a drupal profile, code below: the platform verifies but when creating a site from the platform I get the following error:

> WD php: Error: Call to undefined function mb_strcut() in
>   SearchApiDbService::mbStrcut() (line 2258 of
>   /var/aegir/platforms/pan7/profiles/panopoly/modules/contrib/search_api_db/service.inc).
>   -     error Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.

```
api = 2
core = 7.x

includes[] = drupal-org-core.make   
projects[panopoly][version] = 1.55
```

Contents of drupal-org-core.make

```
api = 2
core = 7.x
projects[drupal][type] = core
projects[drupal][version] = 7.59
```

Does anybody have a working makefile for installing profiles?